# iOS Simulator Debug: Launching 'tel' and 'mailto' Schemes Results in Errors

Tags: ios, flutter, info.plist, lsapplicationqueriesschemes

I have included the following code in my info.plist file:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>mailto</string>
    <string>tel</string>
    <string>https</string>
</array>
```

```
void _makePhoneCall(String phoneNumber) async {
  if (await canLaunchUrl(Uri.parse('tel:$phoneNumber'))) {
    await launchUrl(Uri.parse('tel:$phoneNumber'));
  } else {
    throw 'Unable to make a call to the number $phoneNumber';
  }
}
```

This code works perfectly on Android.
However, when running on an iOS device simulator in debug mode, launching URLs only works for the "https" scheme. Attempting to launch "tel" and "mailto" schemes results in errors. Can't test on real iPhone device.

I expect this to open the phone app and mail app. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: You don't need to query for those url schemes. You can't launch a `tel` or `mailto` url on the simulator.  If you are developing for iOS you really need to have a real iOS device on which to test. The simulator is not a complete replacement.